# How to report column means with datatable filtering Python Dash

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I'm using Python Dash to build an app to where I can display a dash datatable, and report the column means of the datatable (underlying pandas dataframe) as a dash datable right beneath it..  So far, I've tried:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import json
wide_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.24, 2.34, 3.234], [4.24, .45, .06], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


df = pd.DataFrame(wide_data)


df = pd.DataFrame(wide_data)
df_floats = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
df_floats_means = df_floats.mean(numeric_only=True)
df_floats_means = pd.DataFrame(df_floats_means)
df_floats_means_T = df_floats_means.T


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Customer Complaints Dashboard'),
    html.Label('Read and Writing Queries Filtering'),
#     html.Label2('If "Read filter_query" is chosen, use operators (le, ge, <, <=, >, >=) + tag value to filter'),    
#     html.Label3('If "Write filter_query" is chosen, ___'),

    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='filter-query-read-write',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Read filter_query', 'value': 'read'},
        ],
        value='read'
    ),

    html.Br(),

    dcc.Input(id='filter-query-input', placeholder='Enter filter query'), #this is for write functionality

    html.Div(id='filter-query-output'), #this is associated with read screen

    html.Hr(),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-advanced-filtering',
        columns=[
            {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df.columns
            # omit the id column
            if i != 'id'
        ],

        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        page_action='native',
        page_size=10,
        filter_action="native",
    fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
    style_table={'minWidth': '100%'}
    ),

    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id='datatable-query-structure', style={'whitespace': 'pre'}),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Label('Dataframe Means'),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-advanced-filtering2',
        columns=[
            {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df_floats_means_T.columns
            # omit the id column
            if i != 'id'
        ],

        data=df_floats_means_T.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        page_action='native',
        page_size=10,
     #   filter_action="native",
    fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
    style_table={'minWidth': '100%'}
    ),


    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id='datatable-query-structure2', style={'whitespace': 'pre'}),
    html.Hr(),



])


@app.callback(
    [Output('filter-query-input', 'style'),
     Output('filter-query-output', 'style')],
    [Input('filter-query-read-write', 'value')]
)
def query_input_output(val):
    input_style = {'width': '100%'}
    output_style = {}
    if val == 'read':
        input_style.update(display='none')
        output_style.update(display='inline-block')
    else:
        input_style.update(display='inline-block')
        output_style.update(display='none')
    return input_style, output_style


@app.callback(
    Output('filter-query-output', 'children'),
    [Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'filter_query')]
)
def read_query(query):  
    if query is None:
        return "No filter query"
    return dcc.Markdown('`filter_query = "{}"`'.format(query))

@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-advanced-filtering2', 'data'),
    [Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'data')]
)

def update_means(data):
    dff = df
    df_floats = dff.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
    df_floats_means = df_floats.mean(numeric_only=True)
    df_floats_means = pd.DataFrame(df_floats_means)
    df_floats_means_T = df_floats_means.T

    converted_means = df_floats_means_T.to_dict('records')
    return([converted_means])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(threaded=True)
```

But I know that this isn't right as I'm computing the means before any filtering is done in this portion of the app layout `id='datatable-advanced-filtering2'`.  Could you all assist me with the callback?

I'm 100% new to dash, and I haven't seen a lot of guidelines on how to appropriately do this.  Any assistance would be so very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just so I understand, you want the values contained within `df_floats_means_T` to update based on filtering that you're doing within the table with `id=datatable-advanced-filtering`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That's exactly what I'd need

Comment: Cool, so what I mentioned in my answer may work for you then. I believe that when you perform filtering on  the table with `id=datatable-advanced-filtering` it should invoke any callback using that table's `data` attribute as Input.

Comment: May I re-edit my original post to add what I've done?  It's still not working with what I've tried with your answer below, nscale.

Comment: Yeah make those edits and see if we can't figure it out. Also, if you can define `wide_data` within the post so I can run it locally, that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you ncasale. I've just updated it.

Comment: @ncasale One last small update.

Comment: I just updated my answer, let me know if that ends up solving your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the `data` property of your main DataTable as the Input to the callback function, and have the Output be the `data` property of your means DataTable. The structure of that might look something like:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-advanced-filtering2', 'data'),
    [Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'data')]
)
def update_means(data):
    # Use data to construct dataframe
    # Find means using same method used at top of post
    # Convert means df using .to_dict('records')
    # Return converted dict
```

The docs have this to say about filtering (emphasis mine):

> By default, these transformations are done clientside. **Your Dash callbacks can respond to these modifications by listening to the data property as an Input**.

You can read more here: https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/interactivity

**EDIT**

So after a bit of experimentation, I realized that when `filter_action` is set to `'native'`, the filtering of the DataTable doesn't actually update its `data` attribute. Because the attribute is not actually updated, any callback using the `data` attribute as an `Input` will not fire upon filtering. In order to get around this and use the `data` attribute as input to our callback, we need to set `filter_action` to `'custom'`, and then implement the filtering callback ourselves. Luckily, the Dash docs had an example of how to do this here: https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/filtering

Using the information in those docs, I was able to get an example to work. I'll leave it up to you to figure out the inner workings of the filtering method, but the following code runs locally for me and shows the means DataTable updating when the main DataTable is filtered. The only other modification I made was to the `update_means` function whereby I changed it from returning a `list` as you had in your example code, to returning a `dict` which is the correct type for the `data` attribute.

```py
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
from dash import Dash

# Instantiate df and calculate initial means
wide_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1.24, 2.34, 3.234], [4.24, .45, .06], [7, 8, 9]]),
                         columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df = pd.DataFrame(wide_data)
df_floats = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
df_floats_means = df_floats.mean(numeric_only=True)
df_floats_means = pd.DataFrame(df_floats_means)
df_floats_means_T = df_floats_means.T

# Operators used by custom filtering
operators = [['ge ', '>='],
             ['le ', '<='],
             ['lt ', '<'],
             ['gt ', '>'],
             ['ne ', '!='],
             ['eq ', '='],
             ['contains '],
             ['datestartswith ']]

# Initialize app
app = Dash(__name__)

# Init layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Customer Complaints Dashboard'),
    html.Label('Read and Writing Queries Filtering'),
    #     html.Label2('If "Read filter_query" is chosen, use operators (le, ge, <, <=, >, >=) + tag value to filter'),
    #     html.Label3('If "Write filter_query" is chosen, ___'),

    dcc.RadioItems(
        id='filter-query-read-write',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Read filter_query', 'value': 'read'},
        ],
        value='read'
    ),

    html.Br(),

    # this is for write functionality
    dcc.Input(id='filter-query-input', placeholder='Enter filter query'),

    html.Div(id='filter-query-output'),  # this is associated with read screen

    html.Hr(),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-advanced-filtering',
        columns=[
            {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df.columns
            # omit the id column
            if i != 'id'
        ],

        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        page_action='native',
        page_size=10,
        filter_action="custom",
        fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
        style_table={'minWidth': '100%'}
    ),

    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id='datatable-query-structure', style={'whitespace': 'pre'}),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Label('Dataframe Means'),

    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-advanced-filtering2',
        columns=[
            {'name': i, 'id': i, 'deletable': True} for i in df_floats_means_T.columns
            # omit the id column
            if i != 'id'
        ],

        data=df_floats_means_T.to_dict('records'),
        editable=True,
        page_action='native',
        page_size=10,
        filter_action="native",
        fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
        style_table={'minWidth': '100%'}
    ),


    html.Hr(),
    html.Div(id='datatable-query-structure2', style={'whitespace': 'pre'}),
    html.Hr(),



])


@app.callback(
    [Output('filter-query-input', 'style'),
     Output('filter-query-output', 'style')],
    [Input('filter-query-read-write', 'value')]
)
def query_input_output(val):
    input_style = {'width': '100%'}
    output_style = {}
    if val == 'read':
        input_style.update(display='none')
        output_style.update(display='inline-block')
    else:
        input_style.update(display='inline-block')
        output_style.update(display='none')
    return input_style, output_style


@app.callback(
    Output('filter-query-output', 'children'),
    [Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'filter_query')]
)
def read_query(query):
    if query is None:
        return "No filter query"
    return dcc.Markdown('`filter_query = "{}"`'.format(query))


# Callback to re-calculate means after filtering is
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-advanced-filtering2', 'data'),
    [Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', 'data')]
)
def update_means(data):
    # Calculate means from data currently stored in top datatable
    dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    df_floats = dff.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
    df_floats_means = df_floats.mean(numeric_only=True)
    df_floats_means = pd.DataFrame(df_floats_means)
    df_floats_means_T = df_floats_means.T

    # Return means to means datatable
    #THIS NOW RETURNS DICT INSTEAD OF LIST
    converted_means = df_floats_means_T.to_dict('records')
    return converted_means


def split_filter_part(filter_part):
    '''Helper function for custom filtering'''
    for operator_type in operators:
        for operator in operator_type:
            if operator in filter_part:
                name_part, value_part = filter_part.split(operator, 1)
                name = name_part[name_part.find('{') + 1: name_part.rfind('}')]

                value_part = value_part.strip()
                v0 = value_part[0]
                if (v0 == value_part[-1] and v0 in ("'", '"', '`')):
                    value = value_part[1: -1].replace('\\' + v0, v0)
                else:
                    try:
                        value = float(value_part)
                    except ValueError:
                        value = value_part

                # word operators need spaces after them in the filter string,
                # but we don't want these later
                return name, operator_type[0].strip(), value

    return [None] * 3


@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-advanced-filtering', "data"),
    [Input('datatable-advanced-filtering', "filter_query")])
def update_table(filter):
    '''Callback that handles custom filtering of top datatable'''
    if filter is None:
        return df.to_dict('records')
    filtering_expressions = filter.split(' && ')
    dff = df
    for filter_part in filtering_expressions:
        col_name, operator, filter_value = split_filter_part(filter_part)

        if operator in ('eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'):
            # these operators match pandas series operator method names
            dff = dff.loc[getattr(dff[col_name], operator)(filter_value)]
        elif operator == 'contains':
            dff = dff.loc[dff[col_name].str.contains(filter_value)]
        elif operator == 'datestartswith':
            # this is a simplification of the front-end filtering logic,
            # only works with complete fields in standard format
            dff = dff.loc[dff[col_name].str.startswith(filter_value)]

    return dff.to_dict('records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

@ncascale Thank you so much, but there is one small issue here:

```
def update_table(filter):
    '''Callback that handles custom filtering of top datatable'''
    filtering_expressions = filter.split(' && ')
    dff = df
    for filter_part in filtering_expressions:
        col_name, operator, filter_value = split_filter_part(filter_part)

        if operator in ('eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'):
            # these operators match pandas series operator method names
            dff = dff.loc[getattr(dff[col_name], operator)(filter_value)]
        elif operator == 'contains':
            dff = dff.loc[dff[col_name].str.contains(filter_value)]
        elif operator == 'datestartswith':
            # this is a simplification of the front-end filtering logic,
            # only works with complete fields in standard format
            dff = dff.loc[dff[col_name].str.startswith(filter_value)]

    return dff.to_dict('records')
```

It works, but there is an error that pops up that is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is this due to the fact that I must check to see if the parameter passed here "filter" must be None first with an If statement?

Comment: I believe so. The only reason I think you'd get that error is if the filter string is empty, so doing something like `if filter is None: return df.to_dict('records')` should avoid that. I've updated my answer to include that check in the filter callback. I'm no longer seeing the error locally.

Comment: It worked just fine. Thank you, so...so much ncasale.

Comment: Of course! :) I've used Dash a decent amount and remember it being tough to get started with, happy to help. Make sure to mark my answer as the solution so others know the issue is resolved.

Comment: For sure - Accepted :)